# How to exclude a value from string in stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I am using str_detect to replace some strings in my dataframe.  However, because the string is a group where the order changes sometimes  I am having trouble piping together the values and ignore some.

My list looks something like this:

```
c("TONY_B+CAT_A", "TONY_B+JOHN_C+CAT_A")
```

I would like to replace any combination of TONY_B, CAT_A with "BLUE"

and any combination of TONY_B, JOHN_C, CAT_A with "RED"

I have tried replace(data, str_detect(data, "^TONY_B+CAT_A$"), "BLUE")

But this obviously only works in that order, (eg. it ignores CAT_A+TONY_B)

I've tried piping them together, but then I pick up the JOHN_C string as well.

I've tried using the "?!" negative look around, but this seems to fail too.

I don't want to hard code all the combinations, but they could get long and it seems there must be a better way.

Anyone got any tips on how I could fix this?

Comment: For "BLUE", do "TONY_B" and "CAT_A" have to appear next to each other (nothing in between)? Or is it just also having "JOHN_C" makes it "RED"?

Comment: TONY_B and CAT_A have to be there, as well as JOHN_C for it to be RED.  I'm having trouble piping together and excluding certain values.

Comment: `if_else(str_detect(c("TONY_B+CAT_A", "TONY_B+JOHN_C+CAT_A"), "JOHN_C"), "RED", "BLUE")` ?

Comment: @paqmo: presumably there are other strings in the actual data that are missing either "TONY_B" or "CAT_A"

Comment: @Marius unclear as it stands...but probably the case. would that it were so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think the conditions for "BLUE" and "RED" are more about logic than they are about text patterns. IMO, that means you're better off handling them in R code, rather than in regular expressions. It might be possible to express this kind of logic in a big, complicated regular expression, but I think just writing it out in R code is simpler:

```
x = c("TONY_B+CAT_A", "TONY_B+JOHN_C+CAT_A")
has_tony = str_detect(x, "TONY_B")
has_cat = str_detect(x, "CAT_A")
has_john = str_detect(x, "JOHN_C")
# NOTE: the order of these replacements is important,
#   since "RED" is a subset of "BLUE"
x[has_tony & has_cat] = "BLUE"
x[has_tony & has_cat & has_john] = "RED"
```